# How to get real display resolution in Delphi 7 regardless of scale factor?

Tags: windows, delphi, screen, delphi-7, pascal

I have some problems with getting screen resolution in Delphi 7 when scale is more that 125%.

Code I used for testing:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MonId: integer;
  Mon: TMonitor;
  AllMonitorsWidth, AllMonitorsHeight: integer;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;

  Memo1.Lines.Append(Format('Number of monitors: %d', [Screen.MonitorCount]));

  for MonId := 0 to Screen.MonitorCount - 1 do
  begin
    Mon := Screen.Monitors[MonId];

    With Memo1.Lines do
    begin
      Append('');
      Append(Format('--------  Monitor #%d  --------', [mon.MonitorNum]));
      Append(Format('Resolution: %dpx x %dpx', [Mon.Width, Mon.Height]));
      Append(Format('X-offset: %dpx', [Mon.Left]));
      Append(Format('Y-offset: %dpx', [Mon.Top]));
    end;
  end;


  AllMonitorsWidth  := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
  AllMonitorsHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
  With Memo1.Lines do
  begin
    Append('');
    Append('--------  All monitors  --------');
    Append(Format('Resolution: %dpx x %dpx', [AllMonitorsWidth, AllMonitorsHeight]));
    Append(Format('PPI: %d', [Screen.PixelsPerInch]));
  end;
end;
```

For example, I run this test on notebook with 1366x768 display and Windows 7. Results:

- 100% (96 ppi):
  [image]
- 125% (120 ppi):
  [image]
- 150% (144 ppi):
  [image]
- 200% (192 ppi)
  [image]

As you can see on 150% and 200% scale program detects wrong DPI=96 and resolution also incorect.

I think in modern versions of Delphi there are may be fixed. But is there any solution for Delphi 7 without upgrade to newer version?

Moreover there may be more than one display and with different DPIs. So I need to correct get resolution for each of them.

Comment: You need to add a DPI aware manifest to your program. There are lots of posts on this topic if you search.

Comment: Is it possible in Delphi 7?

Comment: Yes, it is possible in Delphi 7, but you will have to set it up manually. See [Setting the default DPI awareness for a process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process)

Comment: Either 1) create a `<app.exe>.manifest` file (where `<app.exe>` is your actual EXE filename) with the appropriate XML in it, then write a `manifest.rc` file that uses resource type 24 (`RT_MANIFEST`) to refer to your `.manifest` file, eg `1 24 "app.exe.manifest"`.  Then you can add a `{$R manifest.res manifest.rc}` directive in your Delphi code to compile and link the `.rc` file into your EXE.

Comment: Or 2) dynamically load `SetProcessDpiAware()`, `SetProcessDpiAwareness()`, and/or `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext()` at runtime (depending on Windows version) and call it at program startup before creating any UI windows.

Comment: Note that handling DPI is more than just setting the process's DPI awareness level. You have to actually query and use the correct DPI to scale your UI elements, and handle changes to the DPI while your app is running.  All of that will have to be done manually in your UI code as well, since Delphi 7 predates DPI-related APIs, so the VCL won't do anything to help you on this.

Comment: I did this back in the Delphi 6 days, it's quite possible.

Comment: Is there more simple way? Adding DPI-aware to my program will lead to big remaking GUI.

Comment: I found [GetSystemMetricsForDpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetricsfordpi) function which can get screen resolution considering DPI, but it available only in Windows 10.

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious, but: upgrading to a modern Delphi will ease your burden - it handles most of it automatically.